# How to use multiple flatMap responses in map operator in different functions?

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

I have been trying to find a way to chain multiple operations inside a map function that comes from the previous flatMap operator.

Current functionality:

```
flatMap(
  someResponse=> combineLatest([
    this.locator.function(someResponse, variable2),
    this.function1(someResponse),
  ])
),
map(([response1, response2]) => this.function3(response1, response2));
```

The desired new functionality is this:

```
flatMap(someResponse =>
  combineLatest([
    this.locator.function(someResponse, variable2),
    this.function1(someResponse),
    this.locator.function2(someResponse, variable3)
  ])
),
map(([response1, response2, response3]) => {
  this.function3(response1, response2);
  this.function4(response3);
})
```

I have tried another map but it gets the previous map response, not the flatMap. I am not fully confident of how each of these operators works. Such as switchMap, contactMap, mergeMap, etc. I could not find a way to do it.

I chained and combined 3 functions in flatMap and then I want to use the responses to do some other operations.

How can I do this?

Comment: So you want to run an observable, then chain the 3 observables in parallel, then call some synchronous functions when the 3 observables have all returned a value?

Comment: that's right. or if any better way to do it rather than this structure.

Comment: What are you attempting to do in `map` in your example?

Comment: If the last calls are synchronous, wouldn't it be elegant to subscribe to the `flatMap` instead of using a `map`?

Comment: They are all mapping some responses that are coming from backends. all functions are returning arrays.

Comment: You just need to change `combinLatest` to `forkJoin` and it should work

Comment: Unfortunately, it doesn't.

Comment: In the function passed to `map` operator in the second version there is no return value. Is this just a typo? If you do not return anything, the `map` operator does not return anything.

Comment: The functions inside the map return an array, these functions are only mapping some backend responses to the local variables. The thing is that I don't know, why the first one works but not the second one? Isn't it allowed to chain different functions in map operators? If it is, why adding one more function to the chain gives an error? What is wrong in this example? They have the same type of response(all returns an array) they are all synchronous etc. Maybe there is a better way to do it though. That's why I am asking.

Comment: @Sojimanatsu: `why adding one more function to the chain gives an error` - what error do you get? Please update in the question.

Comment: The error is Type 'Observable<void>' is not assignable to type 'Observable<Array>'. but this error is not there in the first example, when  I add the second function like in the desired expression, I get the error. I think it is related to what @Picci was saying. But in the first example, I don't return anything either. Why?

Comment: Arrow functions without curly brackets actually translate to function with a return statement. For eg. `map((...) => function(...))` is similar to `map((...) => { return function(...)) }`. So now you know you aren't returning anything from the second snippet.

Comment: Okay, thanks for the tip. then since it already returns something with the first function, it does not allow me to return something else right? so I need to add another chain that returns 3rd function?

Comment: I've posted an answer. Please see if it works for you.

Answer (score 0):

There might some other elegant solution. But at present the following solution should work.

In the first scenario, you are returning the array returned by `this.function3(response1, response2)`. Because arrow functions without curly brackets actually translate to function with a return statement. For eg. `map((...) => function(...))` is similar to writing `map((...) => { return function(...)) }`.

So in the second scenario create an object and push the arrays returned by both the functions. Then return the object.

```js
flatMap(someResponse =>
  combineLatest([
    this.locator.function(someResponse, variable2),
    this.function1(someResponse),
    this.locator.function2(someResponse, variable3)
  ])
),
map(([response1, response2, response3]) => {
  return {
    'result1': this.function3(response1, response2),
    'result2': this.function4(response3)
  }
})
```

Then when you subscribe to the observable, the arrays from functions 1 and 2 can be accessed by `response.result1` and `response.result2` respectively.

Comment: Hi @Michael, thanks for your efforts, but this does not work either. 

Type 'Observable<{ result1: Array1]; result2: Array2]; }>' is not assignable to type 'Observable<Array1>'.

What if I add another operator, but using flatMap response instead of map() response in another chain? (like adding one more map() but using the 3rd functions answer?